# Cpanel wordpress file directory hide for client

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

Good day, im a freelance developer and quick question is how do i hide or disable a client from seeing wp content wp config files of WordPress, they supplied me with cPanel logins and have sensitive files i don't want touched or viewed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, very important to know you that WordPress **Administrator** can able to see the wp_content, wp_config files and so on (if you have no restriction from your host). Why not there are some plugins (ex: Wp File Manager) to direct access on this kind of files.

To prevent it you can change the role **Administrator** to **Editor** or you can restricted the file permission from server.
Thank you
[image]